# enter from database on javascript function declaration

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

I have this sentence in my page:

```
<img alt="Detalles Cliente" 
  title="Detalles Cliente" src="../images/examinar.png" 
  height="16" width="16" style="cursor:pointer;"
  onclick="mostrarSoloLectura('${cliente.nombre}', '${cliente.telefono}',
  '${cliente.direccion}', '${cliente.comentario}')" />
```

And each comes from values I stored in a database, well, ${cliente.comentario} is a text value that comes from a text area and may or may not include new lines, so the problem I'm getting is that when I put it inside this function and it has a new line inside it, javascript cant run the function, so, how can I pass an enter as part of a text argument in a javascript function? should I change the new line to a diferent code from the server? how can I identify to replace, the new line from the text area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If new line is your only concern the you have to change the new line `\n` as `<br/>` in the server side

```
comentario = comentario.replaceAll("\\\n", "<br/>");
```

If your text area contains single quotes or any other symbols that will break the script construction then you have to escape using apache common lang package

```
comentario = StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(comentario);
```

Comment: Thanks! it works with `comentario = comentario.replaceAll("\\\r\\\n", "<br/>");` with out the \\\r it keeps throwing an error.